# How to get name of Facebook user that left comment using FB.Event.subscribe

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to figure out how to get the name of the Facebook user that left a comment in the Comment Social plugin using FB.Event.subscribe and the comment.create event.

I only see 2 properties on the `response` object:

- `response.href`: URL of the page that the comment was left on
- `response.commentID`: ID of the comment thread

Is it possible to implement client side code to get the name of the facebook user that left the comment? I'm trying to save an extra roundtrip for my server to make a call the graph API to get all the comments then try to figure out who the user was that left the most recent one.  I thought that there might be a way to run an FQL query, but I'm at a loss here.

I figured this would be an obvious thing for the facebook event to expose, but their [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) is so poor I haven't been able to see anything.

**Update:** I've tried using FB.api as suggested by another user and using `/me` but I can't use that since hte user leaving the comment hasn't granted me any permissions. This was confusing because they logged in to post the comment in the comment box AND the user's name is public info if you go to the user's facebook page. So I need a way to query the commenting user's name without using `/me` in FB.api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method definitely works to get a name.. but there is a race condition issue if it is a thread that is getting a ton of comments, as the request to get the comments might not get sent before another comment is made:

```js
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(comment) {
    FB.api('comments', {'ids': comment.href}, function(res) {
        var data = res[comment.href].data;
        console.log(data.pop().from.name);
    });
});
```

This works without the user authenticating your app as well.

Comment: This is giving an error ... `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'pop' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

After reading TMC's comment below I realized that it is not possible without permissions. If you want to this then you will have to ask every commenter to grant you basic permissions.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You can use Facebook Javascript SDK function FB.api which works the same way as PHP SDK's api function but returns a JSON string. Have a look at [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) for documentation. You might also like to have a look at [Comment Object Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/).

Comment has a property `from` which gives the `id` and `name` of the user.

Comment: As far I can tell, a Comment ID has a prefix of the Comment thread ID.  However, I see no easy way to get the comment ID. The  `response.commentID` attribute is comment thread ID (e.g. `1234`), and not the specific commentID (e.g. `1234_56789`).

Comment: Turns out this suggestion to use FB.api won't work. I've tried querying "/me" with FB.api but users that leave comments will always return `undefined` for `response.name` because the user hasn't given me any permissions despite login in to use the comment box.  I need another way without using `/me` to FB.api.